# Import iOS 3.2 source code if user has iOS 3.1.3 or lower

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I am using the [MPMoviePlayerViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009269-CH1-DontLinkElementID_4), which is only supported in iOS 3.2+. How would I obtain the source code for this class and import it if the user has iOS 3.1.3 or lower?

Comment: AFAIK you can't, if you require the functionality might as well make 3.2+ a requirement to install the app.

Comment: I want to support 3.1.3 and lower without having to re-implement `MPMoviePlayerViewController`.

Comment: That's an API exposed and coded into that iOS version, you can't just import source code like that

Comment: Apple did open source the iOS API. When I click into, say [iOS 4.3.3](http://www.opensource.apple.com/release/ios-433/), I'm presented with 10 choices. Which one do I download? And what is the class equivalent of `respondsToSelector`? Something like `classExists`?

Comment: What I'm saying is that even if you add the code it many not work as it might rely on some underlying change made in version 3.2 that won't work in other versions.

Comment: I would at least like to look at the source code to see what it's doing so I can create my own version that is backwards compatible.

Comment: I don't think that the source code for that part of iOS is available. From what I can see there it's just the open source components that iOS uses which are available elsewhere (minus the changes that apple has made to them)

Comment: I see, they've pretty much open-sourced useless stuff as required by law.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jesus says, source code for iOS is not available. That's because it's a commercial secret — Apple's view is that they would put themselves at a significant commercial disadvantage if they revealed it.

Your best course of action is to check if `MPMoviePlayerViewController` is available using normal runtime methods, and find a way to use the older [`MPMoviePlayerController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/MPMoviePlayerController) if it isn't. You'll get into that situation on iPhones and iPod Touches only because the original iPad shipped with iOS 3.2 from day one. The latter differs from the former in that you can't take out the view and composite it by any other means and it doesn't play well with tab bar controllers. So they're always full screen. You can add extra views on top but the `MPMoviePlayerController` is always the thing in charge.

Comment: What is the best way to check if `MPMoviePlayerViewController` is available? I was looking for a class analogy to `respondsToSelector`.

Comment: NSClassFromString(@"MPMoviePlayerViewController") will return nil if no class of that name exists.